# PoE to USB Type-C with both power and network?

Tags: network-adapter, poe, usb-c

I can find all the [bits](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XY3Z4MH) and [bobs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F7P8S36) to cobble together something myself, but it would seem that an all in one unit would be a really handy, and obvious, product. Does anyone know of such a device on the market?